# HTTP request from one docker container to another "Cannot assign requested address"

Tags: .net, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have 2 .NET 6 applications, the UI which is in a separate solution and the Service which is in a separate solution. Both solutions, each have their own Dockerfile and two docker containers run at the same time when debugging in Windows, using Visual Studio 2022.

The UI tried to make a restclient request to Service using `https://localhost:44328`. When the request is executed, I get exception `"ex.Message One or more errors occurred. (Cannot assign requested address (localhost:44328))"`

I tried creating a network like this: `docker network create -d bridge srce-network`
and made sure my 2 containers were on the same network. I used this to verify: `docker network inspect srce-network -f "{{json .Containers }}"`

Still the same issue. I also tried to use Docker compose and add this on the Web container solution:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  my.application:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}myapplication
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MY.Application/Dockerfile
    ports:
        - 44361:443
    networks:
      - srce-network

networks:
  srce-network:
    external: true
```

The Service Compose File:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  my.service:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}Myservice
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: My.Service/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "44328:443"
    networks:
      - srce-network
  
networks:
  srce-network:
    external: true
```

Comment: On the bridge network, you use the service names and unmapped port numbers. So if the application needs to talk to the service, it should use `https://my.service:443/`. If you don't need to talk directly to the service from the host, you don't need to map the port on it.

Comment: Thanks. The UI and the Service are on 2 separate solutions, and separate containers. I thought giving it the service name would only WORK, if both UI/Service was in same docker file..Anyhow I tried what you suggested, then that seem to take me past my issue..now I get error "One or more errors occurred. (The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.)"